# copying from one char pointer to another char pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to copy contents of one char array pointer to another array.Inside the for loop, it displays all elements. But outside the for loop it displays only last element in entire array. Following is code snippet

```
char *outhex[81] = {'\0'};
char *temp[81] = {'\0'};

int a, i, k=0, j=0;
uint8_t quotient[81] ;
uint8_t outdec[81];

quotient[81] = {65,00,01,134,160,00,00,01,194,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,01,32,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,15,00,00,00,100,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,06,00,00,8,00,00,00,21,124,00,00,58,152,00,00,03,32,00,00,00,25,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,244};

    for(i = 0; i < 81; i++)
    {
        char remainder;
        j = 0;
        char hexadecimalnum[3]  = {'0'};
        while (quotient[i] != 0)
        {
           remainder = quotient[i] % 16;
           if (remainder < 10)
              hexadecimalnum[j++] = 48 + remainder;
           else
           hexadecimalnum[j++] = 55 + remainder;
           quotient[i] = quotient[i] / 16;
         }
        printf("%s", hexadecimalnum);

        int p =strlen(hexadecimalnum)-1,q=0;

        char ch;
        while(p > q)
        {
            ch = hexadecimalnum[p];
            hexadecimalnum[p] = hexadecimalnum[q];
            hexadecimalnum[q] = ch;
            p--;
            q++;
        }
        printf("\t%s", hexadecimalnum);
        outhex[i] = (&hexadecimalnum);

        printf("     = %d ", i);
        temp[i] = outhex[i];
        printf("\t outhex[%d]    = %s \t %s \t %d \t %d\n", i, outhex[i], temp[i], &outhex[i], &temp[i]);
      }

     for(a = 0; a< 81; a++)
           {
                printf("temp = %s    %d \n", temp[a], &temp[a]);
           }
```

output is :

```
14  41     = 0   outhex[0]    = 41   41      6299904     6300576
0   0     = 1    outhex[1]    = 0    0   6299912     6300584
1   1     = 2    outhex[2]    = 1    1   6299920     6300592
68  86     = 3   outhex[3]    = 86   86      6299928     6300600
0A  A0     = 4   outhex[4]    = A0   A0      6299936     6300608
0   0     = 5    outhex[5]    = 0    0   6299944     6300616
0   0     = 6    outhex[6]    = 0    0   6299952     6300624
1   1     = 7    outhex[7]    = 1    1   6299960     6300632
2C  C2     = 8   outhex[8]    = C2   C2      6299968     6300640
0   0     = 9    outhex[9]    = 0    0   6299976     6300648
0   0     = 10   outhex[10]    = 0   0   6299984     6300656
0   0     = 11   outhex[11]    = 0   0   6299992     6300664
0   0     = 12   outhex[12]    = 0   0   6300000     6300672
0   0     = 13   outhex[13]    = 0   0   6300008     6300680
0   0     = 14   outhex[14]    = 0   0   6300016     6300688
0   0     = 15   outhex[15]    = 0   0   6300024     6300696
0   0     = 16   outhex[16]    = 0   0   6300032     6300704
0   0     = 17   outhex[17]    = 0   0   6300040     6300712
0   0     = 18   outhex[18]    = 0   0   6300048     6300720
1   1     = 19   outhex[19]    = 1   1   6300056     6300728
02  20     = 20      outhex[20]    = 20      20      6300064     6300736
0   0     = 21   outhex[21]    = 0   0   6300072     6300744
0   0     = 22   outhex[22]    = 0   0   6300080     6300752
0   0     = 23   outhex[23]    = 0   0   6300088     6300760
1   1     = 24   outhex[24]    = 1   1   6300096     6300768
0   0     = 25   outhex[25]    = 0   0   6300104     6300776
0   0     = 26   outhex[26]    = 0   0   6300112     6300784
0   0     = 27   outhex[27]    = 0   0   6300120     6300792
0   0     = 28   outhex[28]    = 0   0   6300128     6300800
0   0     = 29   outhex[29]    = 0   0   6300136     6300808
0   0     = 30   outhex[30]    = 0   0   6300144     6300816
0   0     = 31   outhex[31]    = 0   0   6300152     6300824
F   F     = 32   outhex[32]    = F   F   6300160     6300832
0   0     = 33   outhex[33]    = 0   0   6300168     6300840
0   0     = 34   outhex[34]    = 0   0   6300176     6300848
0   0     = 35   outhex[35]    = 0   0   6300184     6300856
46  64     = 36      outhex[36]    = 64      64      6300192     6300864
0   0     = 37   outhex[37]    = 0   0   6300200     6300872
0   0     = 38   outhex[38]    = 0   0   6300208     6300880
0   0     = 39   outhex[39]    = 0   0   6300216     6300888
0   0     = 40   outhex[40]    = 0   0   6300224     6300896
0   0     = 41   outhex[41]    = 0   0   6300232     6300904
0   0     = 42   outhex[42]    = 0   0   6300240     6300912
0   0     = 43   outhex[43]    = 0   0   6300248     6300920
6   6     = 44   outhex[44]    = 6   6   6300256     6300928
0   0     = 45   outhex[45]    = 0   0   6300264     6300936
0   0     = 46   outhex[46]    = 0   0   6300272     6300944
8   8     = 47   outhex[47]    = 8   8   6300280     6300952
0   0     = 48   outhex[48]    = 0   0   6300288     6300960
0   0     = 49   outhex[49]    = 0   0   6300296     6300968
0   0     = 50   outhex[50]    = 0   0   6300304     6300976
51  15     = 51      outhex[51]    = 15      15      6300312     6300984
C7  7C     = 52      outhex[52]    = 7C      7C      6300320     6300992
0   0     = 53   outhex[53]    = 0   0   6300328     6301000
0   0     = 54   outhex[54]    = 0   0   6300336     6301008
A3  3A     = 55      outhex[55]    = 3A      3A      6300344     6301016
89  98     = 56      outhex[56]    = 98      98      6300352     6301024
0   0     = 57   outhex[57]    = 0   0   6300360     6301032
0   0     = 58   outhex[58]    = 0   0   6300368     6301040
3   3     = 59   outhex[59]    = 3   3   6300376     6301048
02  20     = 60      outhex[60]    = 20      20      6300384     6301056
0   0     = 61   outhex[61]    = 0   0   6300392     6301064
0   0     = 62   outhex[62]    = 0   0   6300400     6301072
0   0     = 63   outhex[63]    = 0   0   6300408     6301080
91  19     = 64      outhex[64]    = 19      19      6300416     6301088
0   0     = 65   outhex[65]    = 0   0   6300424     6301096
0   0     = 66   outhex[66]    = 0   0   6300432     6301104
0   0     = 67   outhex[67]    = 0   0   6300440     6301112
0   0     = 68   outhex[68]    = 0   0   6300448     6301120
0   0     = 69   outhex[69]    = 0   0   6300456     6301128
0   0     = 70   outhex[70]    = 0   0   6300464     6301136
0   0     = 71   outhex[71]    = 0   0   6300472     6301144
1   1     = 72   outhex[72]    = 1   1   6300480     6301152
0   0     = 73   outhex[73]    = 0   0   6300488     6301160
0   0     = 74   outhex[74]    = 0   0   6300496     6301168
0   0     = 75   outhex[75]    = 0   0   6300504     6301176
0   0     = 76   outhex[76]    = 0   0   6300512     6301184
0   0     = 77   outhex[77]    = 0   0   6300520     6301192
0   0     = 78   outhex[78]    = 0   0   6300528     6301200
1   1     = 79   outhex[79]    = 1   1   6300536     6301208
4F  F4     = 80      outhex[80]    = F4      F4      6300544     6301216
temp = F4    6300576 
temp = F4    6300584 
temp = F4    6300592 
temp = F4    6300600 
temp = F4    6300608 
temp = F4    6300616 
temp = F4    6300624 
temp = F4    6300632 
temp = F4    6300640 
temp = F4    6300648 
temp = F4    6300656 
temp = F4    6300664 
temp = F4    6300672 
temp = F4    6300680 
temp = F4    6300688 
temp = F4    6300696 
temp = F4    6300704 
temp = F4    6300712 
temp = F4    6300720 
temp = F4    6300728 
temp = F4    6300736 
temp = F4    6300744 
temp = F4    6300752 
temp = F4    6300760 
temp = F4    6300768 
temp = F4    6300776 
temp = F4    6300784 
temp = F4    6300792 
temp = F4    6300800 
temp = F4    6300808 
temp = F4    6300816 
temp = F4    6300824 
temp = F4    6300832 
temp = F4    6300840 
temp = F4    6300848 
temp = F4    6300856 
temp = F4    6300864 
temp = F4    6300872 
temp = F4    6300880 
temp = F4    6300888 
temp = F4    6300896 
temp = F4    6300904 
temp = F4    6300912 
temp = F4    6300920 
temp = F4    6300928 
temp = F4    6300936 
temp = F4    6300944 
temp = F4    6300952 
temp = F4    6300960 
temp = F4    6300968 
temp = F4    6300976 
temp = F4    6300984 
temp = F4    6300992 
temp = F4    6301000 
temp = F4    6301008 
temp = F4    6301016 
temp = F4    6301024 
temp = F4    6301032 
temp = F4    6301040 
temp = F4    6301048 
temp = F4    6301056 
temp = F4    6301064 
temp = F4    6301072 
temp = F4    6301080 
temp = F4    6301088 
temp = F4    6301096 
temp = F4    6301104 
temp = F4    6301112   
temp = F4    6301120 
temp = F4    6301128 
temp = F4    6301136 
temp = F4    6301144 
temp = F4    6301152 
temp = F4    6301160 
temp = F4    6301168 
temp = F4    6301176 
temp = F4    6301184 
temp = F4    6301192 
temp = F4    6301200 
temp = F4    6301208 
temp = F4    6301216
```

Outside for loop, all elements of temp array is containing only last data. Initial elements are overwritten by last element. What is the reason for this? Is there any solution to get all contents array outside 'for loop'.

Comment: Combine initialization of `quotient[81]` with declaration, i.e. write `uint8_t quotient[81] = { ... lots of numbers here ... }` to put the data in the array.

Comment: Just note, that integer literals starting with `0` are in *octal* base.  Be careful with that.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Missing the include statements for the header files.  Missing a 'type' for the `quotient[]` array.  Missing a `main()` function.

Comment: the 'magic' number 81 is scattered throughout the code.  Much better to declare `int quotient[] = {...}'  then all the 81 literals could be replaced with `sizeof( quotient ) / sizeof( quotient[0] )`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `hexadecimalnum[j++] = 55 + remainder;`  the value for 'A' is 65, not 55

Comment: regarding the calculation of `hexadecimalnum[]` the hex digits are being placed in the array in the reversed order.  Suggest replacing `int j=0;` with `int j =2;`  and in the actual assignments, use `j--` rather than `j++`

Comment: regarding: `outhex[i] = (&hexadecimalnum);`  since `hexadecimalnum` is an array, referencing its' name degrades to the address of the array.  so no need (and it is considered an error) to try to take the address of an address.

Comment: regarding: `printf("\t outhex[%d]    = %s \t %s \t %d \t %d\n", i, outhex[i], temp[i], &outhex[i], &temp[i]);`  1) the values in the arrays `outhex[]` and `temp[]` are not NUL terminated strings, so the `%s` format specifier will not work.  2) the proper way to display an address is via the `%p` format specifier and the address must be of type `char *`

Answer (score 3):

This line is the problem.

```
outhex[i] = (&hexadecimalnum);
```

For any value of `i`, it's pointing to the same variable. So `outhex[0]` will be the same as `outhex[1]` for example.

You're also assigning the wrong value to it as well as `&hexadecimalnum` is a `char **` and `outhex[i]` will be `char *`. Your compiler should have flagged this up as an warning.

The correct way to do this is to make a new copy of the string and store it into `outhex[i]`. Like this, for example...

```
outhex[i] = malloc(strlen(hexadecimalnum)+1);
strcpy(outhex[i],hexadecimalnum);
```

or you can use `strdup` which does the allocation and copying in one function call.

```
outhex[i] = strdup(hexadecimalnum);
```

I can't see any difference in `temp` and `outhex` so there probably isn't any call to make a new copy, so `temp[i]=outhex[i]` probably isn't an issue...at least not in the code as provided.

There also a typo on this line

```
char hexadecimalnum[3]  = {'0'};
```

which should be so that your string is `NUL` terminated and will work with the previous fixes.

```
char hexadecimalnum[3]  = {'\0'};
```

Comment: when copying a string, use `strcpy()`, a direct assignment, as in `temp[i] = outhex[i]` will only assign the address of `outhex[i]` to `temp[i]`

Comment: @user3629249 that won't work unless memory is first allocated for `temp[i]`, which as I noted in my answer, there doesn't seem to be any point since `temp` doesn't seem to serve any purpose that `outhex` couldn't provide.